# Rails save draft update in the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model called articles which has a string field that allows users to set their article to draft. When a draft is selected and a user updates the post I would like it to return to the article edit page as if the user selected the published option then I would like for the user to be redirected to the articles index page.

The problem is I cannot get the article to update and redirect back to the post if the draft option is selected. Am I approaching this the wrong way?

**Migration file**

```
def change
    add_column :articles, :status, :string, default: 'Draft'
  end
```

**articles.rb**

```
scope :submitted, lambda { where('status = ?', 2) }
scope :draft, lambda{ where('status = ?', 1) } 

def is_draft?
  self.draft
end
```

**articles controller**

```
  def update
      case @article.status
        when 1 
          @article.status = 'Draft'
        else 2 
          @article.status = 'Published'
      end

      if @article.status == 1 
        @article = article.find(params[:id])
        flash[:notice] = "Successfully Updated" if @article.update_attributes(params[:article])
        respond_with(@article, :location => edit_article_path)
      else
        @article = article.find(params[:id])
        flash[:notice] = "Successfully Updated" if @article.update_attributes(params[:article])
        respond_with(@article, :location => articles_path)
      end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to work with 1/2 values

Model:

```
STATUS_VALUES = {1 => "Draft", 2 => "Published"}

scope :submitted, lambda { where('status = ?', STATUS_VALUES[2]) }
scope :draft, lambda{ where('status = ?', STATUS_VALUES[1]) } 

attr_accessible :_status

after_initialize do
  self.draft! if self.new_record?  # be draft by default
end

def draft!
  self.status = STATUS_VALUES[1]
end

def published!
  self.status = STATUS_VALUES[2]
end

def _status
  STATUS_VALUES.invert(status)
end

def _status=(value)
  case value
  when 1, "1" then self.draft!
  when 2, "2" then self.published!
  else self.draft!
  end
end

def draft?
  self.status == STATUS_VALUES[1]
end

def published?
  self.status == STATUS_VALUES[2]
end
```

Controller:

```
def update
  @article = article.find(params[:id])
  if @article.update_attributes(params[:article])
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully Updated" 
    if @article.draft?
      respond_with(@article, :location => edit_article_path)
    else
      respond_with(@article, :location => articles_path)
    end
  else
    render :action => :edit
  end
end
```

View:

```
<%= f.check_box(:_status, "Published", 2, 1) %>
```